# Python numpy addition error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting a very odd error using a basic shortcut method in python. It seems, unless I'm being very stupid, I get different values for A = A + B, and A += B. Here is my code:

```
def variance(phi,sigma,numberOfIterations):
    variance = sigma
    for k in range(1,numberOfIterations):
        phik = np.linalg.matrix_power(phi,k)
        variance = variance + phik*sigma*phik.T
    return variance
```

This basically just calculates the covariance of a vector autoregression. So for:

```
phi    = np.matrix('0.7 0.2 -0.1; 0.001 0.8 0.1; 0.001 0.002 0.9')
sigma  = np.matrix('0.07 0.01 0.001; 0.01 0.05 0.004; 0.001 0.004 0.01')
```

I get:

```
variance(phi,sigma,10) = 
[[ 0.1825225   0.07054728  0.00430524]
 [ 0.07054728  0.14837229  0.02659357]
 [ 0.00430524  0.02659357  0.04657858]]
```

This is correct I believe (agrees with Matlab). Now if I change the line above to

```
variance += phik*sigma*(phik.T)
```

I get:

```
variance(phi,sigma,10) =
[[ 0.34537165  0.20258329  0.04365378]
 [ 0.20258329  0.33471052  0.1529369 ]
 [ 0.04365378  0.1529369   0.19684553]]
```

Whats going on?

Many thanks

Dan

Comment: `A = A.__add__(B)` != `A = A.__iadd__(B)` if A is mutable

Comment: It's also kind of weird to have a variable in the scope of your function with the same name as the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
variance = sigma
```

If you change that to:

```
variance = sigma.copy()
```

You'll see the correct result.

This is because `+=` actually performs a (more efficient) in-place addition… And since both `variance` and `sigma` reference the same array, *both* will be updated. For example:

```
>>> sigma = np.array([1])
>>> variance = sigma
>>> variance += 3
>>> sigma
array([4])
```